# Xcode How to make a circular slider

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, slider, circular-slider

I am trying to make a circular slider. I don't know where to start really. I have tried downloading ones from github and trying to implement them in my code however, they use older version of swift which i cant debugg. I have tried using cocoa pods for the first time as I found this circular slider: https://iosexample.com/a-powerful-circular-slider-written-in-swift/

Unfortunately my xcode project cant recognise the pod file downloaded (see picture):
[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42eXU.png)

Does anyone know any solutions to these problems or have a simpler approach to obtaining a circular slider.

Thank you!

Comment: You can get the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/taglia3/CircularSlider)

Comment: You can always make one. It should be pretty simple using a few subviews and a pan gesture recognizer. Worst case scenario overriding draw rect which is very easy by now with all the native tools. But your problem may also be solved by fixing your pods if you provide more information. To create a quick checklist ensure your podfile is up to date, when you run pod install confirm there are no issues, make sure you open xcworkspace file after the pods are installed instead of xcodeproj. The last one is quite a candidate.